# Java - repaint component every second?

Tags: java

I would like to repaint component after each second, but it didn't work. What I am trying is:

```
    try{
        while(true){
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            gc.cb.next();
            gc.repaint();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ie){
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

I would advise using a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for this problem, which will periodically fire an `ActionEvent` on the Event Dispatch thread (note that you should only call repaint and / or manipulate Swing components from this thread).  You can then define an `ActionListener` to intercept the event and repaint your component at this point.

**Example**

```
JComponent myComponent = ...
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds

ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    myComponent.repaint();
  }
};

new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Also note that `SwingWorker` is probably **inappropriate** as it is typically used for background tasks that have a defined start and end, rather than a periodic task.

Comment: Did you read the API for the Timer class? I would think the method to use is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not hogging the UI-thread for this. If you're executing this loop in the UI-thread, then the `repaint` event will never be dispatched.

Another note; `sleep` is a static method, and should be invoked as `Thread.sleep(...)`. (There is no way of doing `thatThread.sleep(...)` anyway.)

The "correct" way of doing this is probably to use a `SwingWorker`. Have a look at [the tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

If you provide more code, we can provide better answers.