# Making a Canvas object draw different shapes when different buttons are clicked?

Tags: java, awt

I normally program in Python but some friends asked me a few hours ago if I could help them with their Java homework assignment. So I've been learning Java since about a few hours ago.

Anyway, they need a program which visually demonstrates how aerodynamics affects certain objects when travelling at a high speed. Nothing complicated though, probably just a ball or so, so a simple circle would suffice.

I've just gotten the hang of ActionListeners and stuff, but how could I make the object shown in a Canvas object change when a mouse button is clicked?

Comment: *"I need your help urgently."*  I suggest you hire someone and pay them urgency rates.  Voting to close as 'too localized - a specific moment in time'.

Answer (score 2):

[Add a MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29) to the canvas, and in the `mouseClicked()` method of the listener, change the state of the objects painted by the canvas, and call the canvas `repaint()` method in order for the canvas to repaint itself, based on the modified state.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend extending a `JPanel` and using `paintComponent()` instead of a `Canvas`, as this is pretty outdated AWT stuff. Basically what you need to do is to add a `MouseListener` to whichever palette(`Canvas` or `JPanel`) you end up using and in the overridden `mouseClicked()` of the listener, paint the things that you like. Also call `repaint()` after every change (You could create a Timer to do this for you regularly - see the first answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972651/java-repaint-component-every-second) question).

When it comes down to painting a ball, I would recommend using the Java2D API (look at `Ellipse2D`) instead of plain `drawOval()` (which probably seems like the easy way out at first). The reason in that `Ellipse2D` allows you to use a bunch of very useful methods (see `setFrame()`, for example) and is a "real object" which maintains state. You can easily use composition to create a shape class with your desired behavior, using the `Ellipse2D` as the graphical representation for the shape. It is, however, much more difficult to use `drawOval()` without creating a messy bowl of procedural noodles.

Comment: +1 For various points, but mostly *"a messy bowl of procedural noodles"*.  Mmmm..  noodles.  ;)