# Having problems with the recursion

Tags: java

My goal with this program is to have the bullseye colors switch back and forth. However the colors do not switch it makes new colors instead. The more pressing problem is when i try to repeat it in any way. The screen that comes up when the program is ran is blank and does nothing. When there is no loop the bullseye comes up.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BullSEye extends JPanel
{
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
   {

    super.paintComponent( g );
    Random rand = new Random();

    int top = 2;
    int r = rand.nextInt(256);
    int b = rand.nextInt(256);
    int h = rand.nextInt(256);
    int t = rand.nextInt(256);
    int u = rand.nextInt(256);      
    int v = rand.nextInt(256);

    Color randomColor = new Color(r, h, b);
    Color randColor = new Color(t,u,v);

    //sets colors for first bullseye
    g.setColor(randomColor);    
    g.fillOval( 10, 10, 200, 200 );
    g.setColor(randColor);
    g.fillOval( 35, 35, 150, 150 );
    g.setColor(randomColor);
    g.fillOval(60, 60, 100, 100);
    g.setColor(randColor);
    g.fillOval( 85, 85, 50, 50 );

    try
    {
       Thread.sleep(1000); // do nothing for 1000 miliseconds (1 second)
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //sets colors for second bullseye
    g.setColor(randColor);
    g.fillOval( 10, 10, 200, 200 );
    g.setColor(randomColor);
    g.fillOval( 35, 35, 150, 150 );
    g.setColor(randColor);
    g.fillOval(60, 60, 100, 100);
    g.setColor(randomColor);
    g.fillOval( 85, 85, 50, 50 );

    //recursive call to repeat the back and forth colors
    paintComponent(g);

   }

}

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BullSEyeTest 
{

   public static void main( String args[] )    
   {

      BullSEye panel = new BullSEye();

      JFrame application = new JFrame();

      application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      application.add( panel );
      application.setSize( 230, 250 );
      application.setVisible( true );

   }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code with the loop, since this doesn't have it (and I suppose is the code that "works)

Comment: Just so you know, you shouldn't be calling `Thread.sleep()` in the EDT. That is, where you are drawing.

Comment: The threading should completely removed from the edt. To trigger a repaint you should use a background thread.  With your sleep within the edt thread you block swings eventprocessing so no input is possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues here that are probably contributing to your problem.

First, you are generating random numbers for your colors, and that is why you get different colors every time you run the program (without the recursive call).

If you want the same colors every time, you don't need the random number generator, they would just be constants.

Secondly, recursion is not the right way to re-render the UI in Swing.  Swing provides a 'repaint' method for that on the JComponent, and typically you would call that repaint method from an action listener that is fired from a timer instead of doing that recursively.  Also, you are getting a non-responsive UI because you are telling the Thread to sleep.

Hope that helps answer your question.  Check out this post for some more information on how to implement this:

[Java - repaint component every second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972651/java-repaint-component-every-second)